# What is the most efficient way to integrate metrics collection on dart shelf muti-isolated with Prometheus

Tags: multithreading, dart, http, prometheus

What is the most efficient way to integrate the collection of metrics (Requests/sec) in the multi-isolated dart shelf with Prometheus.

Currently I am using the stream_isolate package and the prometheus_client, with Bidirectional Stream Isolate each isolated
sends a message to main when it receives an http request, when main receives the message it resends it to all isolates, when isolates receive the message I increment the request counter to expose the metrics to Prometheus, I don't know if this is the best way to do this.

```dart
final streamIsolates = <Map<int, BidirectionalStreamIsolate>>[];
void main() async {
  final arguments = ['0.0.0.0', '3161'];
  final numberOfIsolates = 16;
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfIsolates - 1; i++) {
    final streamIsolate = await StreamIsolate.spawnBidirectional(isolateMain,
        debugName: i.toString(), argument: [i, ...arguments]);
    streamIsolates.add({i: streamIsolate});
    streamIsolate.stream.listen((event) => receiveAndPass(event, i));
  }
}
/// receive msg from isolate and send to all isolates
void receiveAndPass(event, int idx) {
  streamIsolates.forEach((item) {
    item.values.first.send(event);
  });
}
Stream isolateMain(Stream inc, dynamic args) {
  final arguments = args as List;
  int id = arguments[0];
  String address = arguments[1];
  int port = arguments[2];
  final streamController = StreamController.broadcast();
  final reg = CollectorRegistry();
  // Register default runtime metrics
  runtime_metrics.register(reg);
  // Register http requests total
  final http_requests_total = Counter(
      name: 'http_requests_total', help: 'Total number of http api requests');
  http_requests_total.register(reg);
  // listen msg from main
  inc.listen((msg) {
    http_requests_total.inc();
  });
  _startServer([id, streamController, reg, address, port]);
  return streamController.stream;
}
void _startServer(List args) async {
  final streamController = args[1] as StreamController;
  final reg = args[2] as CollectorRegistry;
  String address = args[3];
  int port = args[4];
  final app = Router();
  routes(app, reg);
  final handler = Pipeline().addMiddleware((innerHandler) {
    return (request) async {
      // Every time http_request is called, increase the counter by one
      final resp = await innerHandler(request);
      if (!request.url.path.contains('metrics')) {
        //send msg to main
        streamController.add('+1');
      }
      return resp;
    };
  }).addHandler(app);
  final server = await io.serve(handler, address, port, shared: true);
  print('Serving at http://${server.address.host}:${server.port}');
}
void routes(Router app, CollectorRegistry reg) {
  app.get('/', (Request request) async {
    return Response.ok('shelf');
  });
  // Register a handler to expose the metrics in the Prometheus text format
  app.get('/metrics', (Request request) async {
    final buffer = StringBuffer();
    final metrics = await reg.collectMetricFamilySamples();
    format.write004(buffer, metrics);
    return Response.ok(
      buffer.toString(),
      headers: {'Content-Type': format.contentType},
    );
  });
  app.add('GET', '/api/v1/test', (Request request) async {
    final listItems = List.generate(150, (int index) => {'name': 'Jon_$index'});
    return Response.ok(jsonEncode(listItems),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'});
  });
}
```